# Configuring RSS Viewer

Tags: rss

Should I be able to configure a RSS Viewer that reads from another list on my site/farm?

My attempts so far generate this error, first from a list in the same site, then from a list in a neighboring site collection:

"ProtocolError occured trying to complete the request. The server returned a status code of : InternalServerError and the status description is : "( The server denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL)."

Comment: Start with checking your ULS logs for more information, then update the post with that. (You will probably find the problem right there...)

Comment: Thank you. I see your advice on using these logs, elsewhere on the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

You can only use the RSS viewer to pull internal SharePoint content if you're using Kerberos authentication in the farm.  If you aren't running Kerberos, you'll need to use data view web parts most likely.

Comment: Thank you. I know that we certainly _intend_ to be doing so, but I'm not a network administrator so will check with them.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to view an rss feed from an internal site you must turn on intranet calls. The error in ULS for intranet calls looks similar to the one you stated: Cannot find site lookup info for request Uri & Preventing an intranet call.

Using powershell:

```
$farm=get-spfarm   
$farm.properties.disableintranetcalls=$false  
$farm.properties.disableintranetcallsfromapps=$false  
$farm.Update()
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not to use the RSS-wiever webpart. Insert the Content Query and you can import an RSS from your site collection. Microsoft should really do something to inform users about this.

Comment: Thanks Erik, will this show RSS items from the discussion board?